# Solr grouping and highlighting

Tags: java, spring, solr

We are using SolrTemplate in spring to intergrate solr with our application.
For a particular case we would like to have results by grouping on a field and highlighting the matched content in all the documents.This can be acheived by using solr web UI.

Sample Request: 
http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/SearchDocument/select?q=messageContent%3Asan&wt=json&indent=true&hl=true&hl.fl=messageContent&hl.simple.pre=%3Cem%3E&hl.simple.post=%3C%2Fem%3E&group=true&group.field=type_message&group.limit=10

But when we do the same using solrTemplate.queryForHighlightPage(query,test.class) , then we were not able to get the desired results. I can see the grouped content, but not the highlighted content.

Is there anything that am I missing on using solrTemplate